# Ubuntu 21.10 on Hp Omen 15 external diplays stopped working after BIOS udpate

Tags: external-monitor

I just performed a BIOS update and now neither of my external displays work (Displayport or HDMI). I have tried xrandr --auto per some recommendations, but no joy.

lshw -c video shows an UNCLAIMED NVidia diplay and an AMD VGA Compatible controller

Comment: It's UEFI (and has been for the last 10 years), not BIOS. If you updated the firmware then likely Secure Boot has been re-enabled where it previously has been disabled. Just check the settings and act accordingly.

Comment: OK, the HP tool said it was doing a BIOS and indeed a firmware update. I thought I had secure boot enabled before, but I'll try turning it off.

Comment: If you had Secure Boot enabled before then you must have signed the Nvidia drivers otherwise they would have prevented from loading and resulted in the exact situation you're reporting here (unclaimed).

Comment: And yes, many manufacturers and users still use (incorrectly) the name "BIOS" or sometimes "UEFI BIOS" for what is UEFI, a new firmware that replaced BIOS.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a secure boot option in the UEFI firmware, so there's nothing to toggle there.

Comment: It has to be, it's part of the general UEFI specifications. You can run, in the OS, `mokutil --sb-state` to confirm (it'll reply with "enabled" or "disabled"). Here's an in-dept explanation about this tool: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535434/what-exactly-is-mok-in-linux-for . And, of course, you should open Additional Drivers and confirm the correct Nvidia drivers are installed and act accordingly.

Comment: My mistake -- I found it under a section of the firmware configuration menus where I had not expected it. And this seems to have fixed the problem, thanks! I do find it odd that the OS boots ok and everything seems to work *except* for external monitors when this is toggled on, but you were absolutely correct.

Comment: The "unclaimed" was the key word. It means there are no drivers running for the hardware and those drivers are required for enabling the external video outputs.

Comment: Please post a detailed answer explaining what you did to solve this issue.

Comment: I turned off secure boot